# Make UL sub-menu appear behind its containing box that has a shadow effect

Tags: drop-down-menu, z-index, shadow, submenu, css

I have a header strip with a shadow effect and contains navigation links; when you hover over them, a sub-menu appears.

[See test page here](http://s439287245.websitehome.co.uk/)

How can I make the sub-menu appear on a layer BEHIND the header strip? I need the header's box shadow to cast on top of the sub-menu.

Currently the sub-menu ( `.main-navigation li ul` ) has a z-index lower than the header strip ( `.site-header` ) but this is having no effect. I've tried giving it a negative z-index but this puts it behind the content (therefore hidden) and the links no longer work - I've read this is a common problem so I'd like to avoid using a negative z-index.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index might not be the solution in this case, due to the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) of elements. Without re-ordering your html, you might try this trick using box-shadow on a pseudo-element attached to your sub-menu. For example:

```
.main-navigation li ul { display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.main-navigation li ul:before { content: ""; display: block; width: 160%; height: 10px; margin-left: -30%; box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ItuXUjo/3). Note that this is only one possible solution, as there are likely other ways to achieve the same effect.

The text content should already naturally appear behind the shadow of the header since it is an adjacent sibling element, ordered after the header in the html. (I added a background image to the content div in the demo to show this.)

Comment: Thank you so much, excellent answer! One question - for the pseudo-element I noticed that when I changed the width to 100%, the shadow is not the full width of the ul sub-menu... where is the pseudo-element getting/inheriting its width from?

Comment: Yes, the width (width:160%) is just arbitrary. It could be any width that works for you that extends it over both sides of the sub-menu, since the sub-menu hides the overflow. If 100% width is necessary for some reason, you'd have to play around with the margins or styling of elements within the sub-menu, as they affect pseudo-elements as well.

Comment: It appears that the pseudo-element gets the width from the content-box area, i.e. _inside_ the padding area. This explains why you had to set it above 100% to make it extend across the whole sub-menu.